# The package linux-headers-4.13.0-37 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade

I would like to ask one solution regarding update and upgrade process. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS xenial version. I found one problem statement:

> E:The package linux-headers-4.13.0-37 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

when I try to update. I am not able to open my synaptic. Please suggest me to get rid of the problem.